# How do I link the is_org_admin field in the User model to the org_admin field in the Organization model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create some models in Django. I currently have the following: User and Organization. One of the fields in the User model is "is_org_admin", which is a boolean. How should I link this field to the "org_admin" field in the Organization model? Here's the simplified code:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    id = ...
    org_admin = models.OneToOneField("users.User"...


class User(AbstractUser):
    id = ...
    is_org_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    organization = models.ForeignKey("organizations.Organization", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make separate model for the `Organization` related details. Do not enforce it into `User` Model. You can do something like this:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    id = ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)    

class Employee(models.Model):
    id = ...
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_org_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```